# Hurwitz Polynomial - Why does continued fraction expansion work?

Tags: complex-analysis, control-theory, network

While checking whether the given polynomial is Hurwitz or not, we perform continued fraction expansion.  We were taught how to perform this check(i.e) look at the sign of the coefficients of the quotients after performing the normal expansion steps.

I can understand why this method would work for a normal fraction like for example $\frac{158}{18}$. But, why separating a **single** polynomial into **odd** and **even terms** and dividing them(and invert and continue) yields all positive terms in the quotients for a Hurwitz polynomial?

Comment: Are you referring to the Routh-Hurwitz criterion? If so, there are plenty of hits on Google

Comment: @Chu Right now, we are being taught two methods to check whether the given polynomial is Hurwitz or not. (1)Routh's array (2)Continued Fraction Expansion(I've a feeling both are the same, though). Whenever I search for math behind Routh's array, I get how the "procedure" but not the math hiding behind. And I couldn'tfind this continued fraction expansion anywhere, and hence I posted

Comment: I guess this subject is addressed in complex analysis and control theory.

Comment: @NoChance I couldn't find the math behind it anywhere on the net( always as saw as I could see)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject is beyond my knowledge. However, I came across the following proofs, I hope you find any value in either of them.

[1-Paper-Elementary proof of the Routh-Hurwitz test by Gjerrit Meinsma](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7638/11603b22f399b3f24d9501013e093acb5735.pdf)

[2-paper -A NETWORK PROOF OF A THEOREM ON HURWITZ POLYNOMIALS
AND ITS GENERALIZATION - By T. R. BASHKOW and C. A. DESOER](https://www.ams.org/journals/qam/1957-14-04/S0033-569X-1957-85862-2/S0033-569X-1957-85862-2.pdf)

3-Chapter 4 - Page 75 of:

[Google Books:A Mathematical Introduction to Control Theory by Shlomo Engelberg](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=niey4jurEsQC&pg=PA75&dq=Hurwitz%20polynomial%20theoretical%20proof&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ8Iqc_-PkAhWlBWMBHSgfCgUQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)